# Name for 'mmm' sound

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> **Mmm**, this cake is delicious.

Does this sound have a name, or does it belong to a category of sounds that has one?

Is there a verb that means "to say *Mmm*"?

I'm searching for either a word or phrase that doesn't include actually writing "Mmm".

Comment: This is an opinion (hence, the comment instead of answer), but IMO, "Mmm" is a kind of closed-lip moan that can be used to indicate something's yummy, or to fill space when trying to answer a question or an ambiguous non-committal sound when you're not quite sure what to say or if you don't want to say anything but acknowledge the other person with an audible response.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I like it! I'm trying to work out how to turn that into a shorter phrase. How about "the yummy moan" or "the yummy moan of delight"?

Comment: [Strange nobody did post this yet : ))](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t05G0983BcI)

Comment: And the next question is: *Name for 'hmm' sound*

Comment: @ermanen In the vein of the top voted answer, "Thinking Sound", of course...

Comment: @KristinaLopez I would differentiate between the *pleasure* sound "mmm", and the *contemplation* sound "mmm" (just as we have "see" and "sea", which sound the same, but have different meanings). The former can indeed be called a closed-lip moan, but that seems less appropriate for the latter. (Curiously, Merriam Webster defines "moan" only as a pain sound, and makes no mention of pleasure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on the kind of *mmm* we would be talking about, but I call at least some of these sound a **murmur**.

> a :  a low indistinct but often continuous sound
>
> b :  a soft or gentle utterance

(The on-line Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 21):

The *Mmmm* syllable can be several syllables, with many conventional meanings,
like *MMM-mmm* or *mmm-MMM*, which can respectively be 'no' and 'yes' in many contexts.

It's described phonetically as a ***syllabic voiced bilabial nasal continuant***;
in IPA it's **[ṃ]** (Unicode 1643; UTF8 E1 89 83; Latin small letter M with dot below).
Similar to the **[ṇ]** as in *certain* /'sərtṇ/, which is a syllabic voiced **alveolar** nasal continuant.

If you turn off the voicing at some point, you can put an /h/ sound anywhere, like *MMM-hmmm*; this can be done without moving the tongue, since voicing is controlled through the larynx and uses no other musculature.

The one that means "this is delicious" would be classified as an interjection,
or as a conversational particle, like *uh-huh, Really?* and the like.

Comment: +1, though the IPA is [m̩] (with U+0329 _combining vertical line below_), not [ṃ] with a dot. As far as I know, a dot below has no meaning in IPA and _ṃ_ is—again, as far as I know—only really used in transcribing Sanskrit and certain other Indo-Aryan languages, and as a fallback variant of _m̧_ (m with cedilla) used in Marshallese.

Answer (score 20):

In the 1974 Mel Brooks film, *Young Frankenstein,* there is a famous scene where this is referred to as the "Yummy Sound." Maybe not an authoritative source, but entertaining nonetheless.

Comment: _Yummy Sound_ is what I thought immediately, but I didn't l know where I got it from.  The film was probably it.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is an Americanism, but when imitation voracious eating, people will make the sound "ahm" or "ahm nom nom". Perhaps "mm" is derived from that imitation of eating.

Answer (score 13):

> Mmm, this cake is delicious.

*Mmm* is an interjection, formed by means of [**onomatopoeia**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/onomatopoeia?s=t):

> 1. the formation of a word, as cuckoo, meow, honk, or boom, by imitation of a sound made by or associated with its referent.
> 2. a word so formed.

Comment: I'm curious...what is the referent for "mmmm"?  (So far, though, I think "interjection" is the best answer for this question!)

Comment: To be more specific, *mm* is an expressive interjection for satisfaction (in OP's example). It can express other things as well depending on the context.

Comment: _Mmm_ isn’t really onomatopoeia, as @Kristina indirectly points out. Onomatopoeia is **imitation**, more specifically **mimicking**, and _mmm_ doesn’t really mimick anything. It is some variant of [sound symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism), perhaps best a subtype of [ideophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone), but I’m not aware of a specific name for cases like this.

Comment: It is listed as onomatopoeia, though, and in multiple sources, too, including here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_onomatopoeias Maybe the reasoning is it imitates the noise of delicious food being eaten. Your mouth is full, you're eating, air goes through your nose, hence the 'mmm'.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for ***humming***?

***[To hum](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hum):***

> - To emit a continuous low droning sound like that of the speech ***sound (m) when prolonged.***

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Perhaps @GregRos could _hum his approval_?

Answer (score 2):

The ODO categorise words like *mmm*, *um*, *hmmm* and *er* as **exclamations**.

Obviously, exclamation is a broader term than just the above, and includes words like *hooray* and *howzat*.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mm?q=mmm#mm-2

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this sound referred to as "The 60 htz Smile" when looking at
someone attractive.
(I believe in the book for "Hackers")

Answer (score 0):

It's called ***campbelling*** or ***campbell souping***, from their famous slogan:

> M'm! M'm! Good!

Comment: How interesting. It may be famous, but I've never heard of it (as a native British English speaker). For everyone's benefit, it's always a good idea to offer some supporting evidence for your answers. Can you provide any sources, references or links?

Comment: http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=M'm+M'm+Campbell+soup

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ScW5_VlaC8

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=campbell

Comment: Thank you - I guess the nearest British equivalent is ["Ah! Bisto!"](http://www.adslogans.co.uk/site/pages/gallery/ah-bisto8361.php)